# TestNG a method to exit out of a series of test cases

Tags: java, testng

I have a series of test cases that run in a chain one after the other and one of them needs to be modified.

This series of test cases that depend on each other and use TestNG's dependsOnMethods annotation, they are all under a single dot java file.
In this series of 5 test cases, I have a NEW condition where within test case 3, I would like to exit out if a certain condition occurs and end the test case without running test cases 4 and 5.

So far I tried with System.exit(0) and it works except that it's not pretty and it messes the logging, html reporting functionality since its an abrupt end of the test case.

example:

```
if (condition)) {
   system.exit(0);
}
else {
 // continue like before
}
```

Is there a proper test-ng way of exiting out of the test case ?

Comment: Not sure this will solve your problem though, 
Have you tried `return` instead of `system.exit(0)`?

Comment: unfortunately, it will still run the next test case if its a normal return and if its an error return, it will still end abruptely

Comment: I can think of two ways to do this.  First way is to set a variable flag, and then access that variable in test 4.  If the flag is true, then throw a SkipException.  The second way would be to throw an Exception.  The only problem with this is that it will say that test case 3 has failed.

Comment: @Twosingleton CAn you show some pseudo code for your test case. May be that can help to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr.Ti

Using SkipException was the best available option and that is what I ended up using.

testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/SkipException.html